# If I want to integrate Innr with home assistant, does there need to be a component for it?

Tags: zigbee, philips-hue, home-assistant

So I bought some "Innr" products, namely zigbee bulbs and plugs. For my hub, I decided to go the raspberry pi + hass.io route.

After I bought everything however, I noticed, that there is actually no component on https://www.home-assistant.io/components/#search/ for Innr specifically.

Does this mean, that Innr product won't work with home assistant?

Innr is supposedly compatible with the hue bridge. Home Assistant has a component for the hue bridge.

Would it work if I use the hue component for that?

I kind of thought, that most zigbee products should work with my zigbee equipped raspberry pi, even if there isn't a specific component. Is this assumption true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Innr Zigbee light works with Home Assistant.

**The long version**:
As with any other Zigbee light, there are two ways to connect it with Home Assistant:

- Pair the innr light with a Zigbee hub that is supported by HA. For example, innr works fine with the hue bridge which [integrate well with HA](https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/hue/).
- Connect an external Zigbee antenna with the raspberry pi, use the [ZHA integration](https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/zha) and pair the innr light (and other Zigbee products as well) directly with HA, no external hub is required.

When using the second option, make sure to purchase a [supported antenna](https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/zha#known-working-zigbee-radio-modules).

On my setting, I had a hue bridge gen 1 which I ditched after Philips *decided to reduce its functionality.
I'm using [Elelabs antenna](https://elelabs.com/products/elelabs-zigbee-shield.html) connected to the raspberry pi. The installation was not straightforward but is documented very clearly.
All my Zigbee products work very well with it (hue, innr, tradfri, sonoff).

Note that innr bulbs, at least the model I have, do not support the HA light integration option for transition.

* *[Paul Hibbert about Philips decision to axe gen 1 (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCP26Tb2a4A&t=115s)*

Comment: Thanks, I ended up getting a zigbee antenna, raspbee and it works fine with HA alone without the bridge. It can't work with the native app of innr though.